# How to make an automatic savepoint in Flink Stateful Functions application?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-statefun

I am trying to dive into the new Stateful Functions approach and I already tried to create a savepoint manually (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-statefun-docs-release-2.1/deployment-and-operations/state-bootstrap.html#creating-a-savepoint).

It works like a charm but I can't find a way how to do it automatically. For example, I have a couple millions of keys and I need to write them all to savepoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your question about how to replace the `env.fromElements` in the example with something that reads from a file, or other data source? Flink's DataSet API, which is what's used here, can read from any `HadoopInputFormat`. See [DataSet Connectors](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/batch/connectors.html#dataset-connectors) for details.

There are easy-to-use shortcuts for common cases. If you just want to read data from a file using a `TextInputFormat`, that would look like this:

```java
env.readTextFile(path)
```

and to read from a CSV file using a `CsvInputFormat`:

```java
env.readCsvFile(path)
```

See [Data Sources](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/batch/#data-sources) for more about working with these shortcuts.

If I've misinterpreted the question, please clarify your concerns.

Comment: Iet's imagine I have a Stateful Functions app and  function with a @Persisted annotated field. I want to call this function many times.

 In classic Flink streaming I can execute something like `flink savepoint` and it will create snapshot of all my entire state. Than I can use created savepoint to restore state after restarting or smth else.

Is it possible to do the same with Stateful Functions app?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. The documentation you linked to in your question is explaining how to bootstrap a savepoint without having to first run a stateful functions app. But like any other Flink streaming application, you can take a savepoint from a running stateful functions app with either `flink savepoint` or `flink stop`.